# How to create separate UI objects for separate accordion tableview parent and child cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to create `accordion tableview` with multiple `tableviewcells` using `iOS` `storyboard`. Below open source code to I am adding multiple tableview separate `parent` and `child` cells using `iOS` `storyboard`. In this open source code developed single tableview cell for both parent and child so same `UI` replacing, But I need to make separate cells for both. Please make some modification and give some solutions.

[image]

https://github.com/singhson/Expandable-Collapsable-TableView

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple way to achieve the same :

> 1.) create custom Parent cell (say MenuParentCell)
>   2.) create custom Child  cell (say MenuChildCell)
>   3.) create a viewcontroller (say Menu) and drag and drop Tableview in it  4)  set delegate and datasource

now :
in cellForRowAtIndexPath write code like this :

```
 MenuItem *menuItem = [APPDELEGATE.FinalMenuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (menuItem.isParent)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mMenuParentCell";
        MenuParentCell *cell = (MenuParentCell*)[mMenuTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //show MenuSelectedIndicationImage
        cell.mMenuSelectedIndicationImage.hidden = NO;
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuParentCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (MenuParentCell*)mMenuParentCell;
        }

        cell.mMenuItemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:menuItem.mIconName];
        cell.mMenuItemLabel.text = menuItem.mItemName;

        if (menuItem.isSelected)
        {
            cell.mMenuSelectedIndicationImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_Up_Arrow_Icon_white.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.mMenuSelectedIndicationImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_Down_Arrow_Icon_white.png"];
        }


        }



        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mMenuChildCell";
        MenuChildCell *cell = (MenuChildCell*)[mMenuTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuChildCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (MenuChildCell*)mMenuChildCell;
        }

        cell.mMenuItemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:menuItem.mIconName];
        cell.mMenuItemLabel.text = menuItem.mItemName;



        return cell;
    }
```

*note - MenuItem is a custom class which is used to store whether parent cell is selected or childcell.
And once you select reload the tableview .
Hope it helps .

Comment: I have created everything but I am confusing inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I am loading data from plist.@Shobhakar Tiwari

Comment: wherever you fetching data doesnt matter . Just put it into an array and populate it in cellforrowatindexpath , but initially only show those data which needs to show in parent cell okey! once user click on any cell then again add item into the array and populate

Comment: No for me its complicated. I am a new for this. Give me some example please @Shobhakar